# URL rewriting with .htaccess not passing parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using php. I want to redirect every request to the index.php file and access parameters there, for example, mysite.com/a should redirect to mysite.com/index.php?id=a so that I can access the param in my code using $_GET["id"], To do this, I have created a .htaccess file with following code.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule [a-z] index.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

note: here I am considering every request with a lowercase letter.

I am trying to access id in my index.php file like this:

```
<?php
echo "sample redirection: <br/>";
echo $_GET["id"];
?>
```

This is redirecting but not passing the parameter. so my output is like this:

```
sample redirection:
```

Its not printing the parameter. Help.

Comment: if you are using integers, you didn't add the integers to your rewriterule.

Comment: am not using integers, right now, I need solution for alphabets only.

Answer (score 1):

You need a dollar sign after the `[a-z]`.

```
RewriteRule ([a-z])$ index.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Note that `[a-z]` will only match ONE letter. To match any string of letters, use:

```
 RewriteRule ([a-z]*)$ index.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: You are passing letters to your page right? `[a-z]` is the set of letters a-z (pretty obvious) so trying to pass numbers as a parameter won't work.

Comment: Also, do you have `mod_rewrite` turned on in Apache?

Comment: I want anything after "mysite.com/" as parameter, I am not passing numbers as parameters, how can I access that parameter in code?

Comment: Yes, I don't think without mod_rewrite turned on, it would have redirected to index.php, right?

Comment: Just edited my answer. It works on my local server, just tested it.

Comment: Another problem, this time more confusing, its writing "php" on whatever am passing? :/ for ex. mysite.com/ipj and its printing "sample redirection: php".. :/ what the fuss is that now? :/

Comment: I don't know. It did not do that for me on my server. What exactly are you passing as the parameter?

Comment: And no matter what it is just saying "php", it doesn't have your parameter included at all in the output (nothing like "ipjphp", for example)?

Comment: I have one more project on my local server which is based on zend framework, so it also use .htaccess, can there be any over riding problem? am new with .htaccess.